# How to intercept all onClick events in Android?

Tags: android, onclick, frida

I am using [Frida](https://github.com/frida/frida) to intercept my Android application events.

Let's say I have an Activity called `MainActivity` and in there I have a function called `sendMessage`:

```
public void sendMessage(View view)
{
    Log.i("MainActivity", "MainActivity: button clicked");
}
```

In my activity_main.xml, I have a single button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10mm"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="My Button"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"/>
```

Note the android:onClick="**sendMessage**" - this tells the android app to look for a function called `sendMessage` and execute it whenever the button is clicked.

My python script to use Frida and intercept the `sendMessage` event looks like this:

```
import frida, sys

def on_message(message, data):
    if message['type'] == 'send':
        print("[*] {0}".format(message['payload']))
    else:
        print(message)

jscode = """
Java.perform(function () {
  // Function to hook is defined here
  var MainActivity = Java.use('com.example.androiddemo.MainActivity');

  // Whenever button is clicked
  var sendMessage = MainActivity.sendMessage;
  sendMessage.implementation = function (v) {
  
    // Show a message to know that the function got called
    send('CLICK START');

    // Call the original onClick handler
    sendMessage.call(this, v);

    // Log to the console that it's done, and we should have the flag!
    console.log('CLICK END');
  };
});
"""

process = frida.get_usb_device().attach('com.example.androiddemo')
script = process.create_script(jscode)
script.on('message', on_message)
print('[*] Running CTF')
script.load()
sys.stdin.read()
```

This works fine, but it requires that I know the name of the function (sendMessage) beforehand.
Rather, I would like to intercept the generic `onClick` calls.

Any idea how I can do this?